# mysql OR fail to give desired result

Tags: mysql

Please refer to the 2 tables from the picture below :
[image]

Code :

```
$query41 = "SELECT  p.message FROM friendship f
JOIN messageslive p
ON p.username = f.frenusername OR p.username = f.username
WHERE f.username = '{$username1}' OR f.frenusername = '{$username1}'
ORDER BY
p.id DESC
LIMIT 16";
$result41 = mysql_query($query41,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
confirm_query($result41);
while($msginfo = mysql_fetch_array($result41)){
        $msg = $msginfo['message'];
        echo $msg . "<br/>";
}
```

Output :

```
live
sss
ssa
ddd
asa
(dance2)
asaaa
ssa
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
```

Question : Why the output show duplicated `(bluek2)`? How to fix the bug? I want to show the latest 16 posts which are posted by zac1987 and zac1987's friends too. The expected output should look the same as the records in table messageslive, eg :

```
live
sss
ssa
ddd
asa
(dance2)
asaaa
ssa
(bluek2)
jjj
vv
(comp2)
(sad2)
(dance7)
```

Comment: It's probably because you have multiple `zac1987` users in your `friendship` table. Out of curiosity, what is the desired results since this current query is giving "undesired results"?

Comment: @cwallenpoole, sorry, confirm_query is just my own function to display the error message if there is an error.

Comment: @Dirk, I have update my question to show the desired results. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric J, tested Distinct, results are not the 1 that I want. Sad case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need the join to the `friendship` table?

```
SELECT p.message
    FROM messageslive p
    WHERE p.username = '{$username1}'
    ORDER BY p.id DESC
    LIMIT 16
```

If you're just trying to establish existence of a friendship, perhaps:

```
SELECT p.message
    FROM messageslive p
    WHERE p.username = '{$username1}'
        AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                       FROM friendship f
                       WHERE f.username = p.username
                           OR f.frenusername = p.username)
    ORDER BY p.id DESC
    LIMIT 16
```

Comment: i want to show 16 latest posts which are posted by many friends of zac1987, not only zac1987. In other words, I want to show my own posts and my friends' posts too. So I need to join the friendship table.

Comment: @zac1987 what is your expected output?

Comment: i don't understand your 2nd codes, I have tested it, output is just (bluek2)
jjj which are posted by zac1987 only. But I want to show the posts which posted by zac1987's friends.

Comment: @daking963, I want the output look exact like the records in table messageslive. `live
sss
ssa
ddd
asa
(dance2)
asaaa
ssa
(bluek2)
jjj
vv
(comp2)
(sad2)
(dance7)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this and it should work.

```
$query41 = "SELECT  p.message FROM friendship f
JOIN messageslive p
ON p.username = f.frenusername OR p.username = f.username
WHERE f.frenusername = '{$username1}'
ORDER BY
p.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 16";
```

Comment: wow, almost get the desired output but still got something wrong, the output is `live
sss
ssa
ddd
asa
(dance2)
asaaa
ssa
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
(bluek2)
jjj
jjj
jjj
vv
(comp2)`, as u can see there are duplicated value. Why? I can't use DISTINCT because some friends might send the same post.

Comment: It shows 3 x duplicated zac1987's post because there are 3 of "zac1987" in the field of "frenusername" in friendship table. How to add "DISTINCT" for "frenusername" field?

Comment: and when I change $username1 == "zac1987" to $username1 == "micellelimmeizheng1152013142", output is blank. Sad case.

Comment: Did you use the exact query? There is no `f.username` for `zac1987`. If you are going to search for `micellelimmeizheng1152013142` then use `f.username` as there is no `micellelimmeizheng1152013142` in the `freusername` so it will give you zero output

Comment: it is okay, i got the answer from other forum already http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=340572.0 thanks anyway.